# Group DataTable by column and convert to List<DataTable>

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a DataTable that looks like the below:

```
Category | Amount
Food     | 10
Drink    | 20
Clothes  | 50
Drink    | 30
Food     | 40
Clothes  | 5
```

I want to *group* it by the **Category** column and *convert* each similar grouping into a **DataTable** and place it inside a **List**. So I need to have **3** DataTables like the below:

**DataTable 1**

```
Category | Amount
Food     | 10
Food     | 40
```

**DataTable 2**

```
Category | Amount
Drink    | 20
Drink    | 30
```

**DataTable 3**

```
Category | Amount
Clothes  | 50
Clothes  | 5
```

Any advice on how to achieve the above?
I can only find questions that want to have an output of 1 DataTable.

Comment: You should post your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Linq to objects (and Linq to Dataset) this way

```
List<DataTable> tablesByCategory = 
    table.AsEnumerable().
          GroupBy(r => r.Field<double>("Category")).
          Select(g => 
          {
              DataTable dt = table.Clone();

              foreach (DataRow r in g)
              {
                  dt.ImportRow(r);
              }

              return dt;
          }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! Just added a ToList() at the end so I have a List<DataTable> instead of IEnumerable<DataTable>